# Google indexing issue for keyword 'StackOverflow'

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, search, google

<del>Maybe this is a temporary issue. I will check later in the night today and update/close this thread. [2013-02-27]</del> For most of the world, this issue should now be resolved and non-repro, and the general consensus is that it was a Google glitch!

---

I searched for 'StackOverflow' on Google UK, both via the Omnibar and the Google UK homepage. The resultant [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator): [www.google.co.uk/#q=stackoverflow&...](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=stackoverflow&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.42965579,d.d2k&fp=dd4fe0fc47989d3d&biw=1366&bih=643&pf=p&pdl=300)

Displayed results ([larger image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FW6q.png)):

[image: Error in Google results for Stack Overflow]

Actual page on [doioig.gov](http://www.doioig.gov/) ([larger image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzWmE.png)):

[image: doioig.gov screenshot]

This has no resemblance to the content displayed by Google.

I have tested this using [Chrome Incognito](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome#Privacy_mode) without logging into Google so there is no [search bubbling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_bubble) and also no plugins on Chrome that are playing these tricks.

I am not tagging this as a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) as it seems unlikely that this is an issue within Stack Exchange control.

---

Searching for `stackoverflow` on the US or some other region specific site, this effect is not observed. But searching explicitly for `stackoverflow doioig` brings up a slightly different result:

[Larger Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ugs3n.png)
[image: Other regions]

Comment: No repro. I am getting http://stackoverflow.com as the first result.

Comment: Repro, I'm seeing what Pratik is seeing

Comment: @Pekka웃 - I am on google.co.uk, as in the screenshot. Are you on .de?

Comment: @Oded yup, http://i.stack.imgur.com/BpyFB.png Maybe we are witnessing a natural miracle that occurs once a decade: a bug on Google. We will be telling our grandchildren about this :)

Comment: Norepro too, also stackoverflow.com here (google.uk). Also stackoverflow.com on google.de.

Comment: Regardless - nothing we can do. This is a google issue, and seeing the disparate results, probably transient.

Comment: Repro, when going to my *own* Google (google.no).

Comment: @Oded yeah. It's a genuine bug though: it's showing my Google Plus friends' +1's for the real Stack Overflow on that result. (ah, and the quick links as seen on bPratik's screen shot)

Comment: @Pekka웃 - Glad it's not just me... although the exclusivity was appealing!

Comment: Maybe, must maybe some developer put up a SO page on the site to knowingly steal the page rank, and later removed it. This is just the final phases that we may be seeing on it...

Comment: That site (doioig.gov) looks like a scam site. It has that slightly seedy "built hastily to phish some data" feeling to it. (It seems to be for real, though)

Comment: @bPratik but why would Google show SO's quick links and stuff on it? That doesn't make sense. It must be a bug.

Comment: Repro on google.ca, too.

Comment: Seems fixed on Google.de now.

Comment: For me, it shows up correctly for every site *except* my actual region (unless I explicitly search for 'stackoverflow doioig'). Might have something to do with that?

Comment: I've reproduced it here. I'll report it internally tomorrow - thanks for bringing it up.

Comment: Repro on google.com.au.

Comment: Also reported [here](http://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?pid=12733381) (in French).

Comment: Yes I am getting this. I reported it on my blog yesterday found [here](http://www.jacobtomlinson.co.uk/2013/02/27/has-stack-overflow-been-hacked/)

Comment: Still seeing this

Comment: I have the same result as you. Reproduced many times.

Comment: Also for [Google HK](https://www.google.com.hk/search?q=stackoverflow)

Comment: @Jon Skeet Could you gently ask the search guys what caused this? A lot of people here would love to hear a technical explanation. - As long as it's not too sensitive. Of course, we don't want people gaming the system.

Comment: @AlexandreJasmin - try: http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=5311151

Comment: @bPratik I know. But I'd still like to know how a cut and paste mistake on an unrelated government site can nudge the SO homepage off Google Search.

Comment: @AlexandreJasmin: I'll keep an eye on it internally (I didn't report it in the end as I couldn't reproduce it the next day - but it *has* been reported) but I doubt that I'll be able to give any feedback here about what happened. I'll see though.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

So apparently this is pointing to an issue with google.  If you use fiddler or wget and request http://www.doioig.gov you will see the following response:

[image: Fiddler for doioig]

Notice the meta refresh pointing at http://stackoverflow.com - it seems that a developer copied and pasted the answer from here without changing the example URL:

https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/5411601/3

Apparently doioig.gov has pretty significant rank and authority with google - so much so that it is currently impacting what is displayed and linked for our domain.  We will try to get the attention of people at google and see where this goes.

Credit goes to http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=5311151 - there's a discussion going on about this right now.

**EDIT:**  It appears that google has taken action and resolved this issue.  At this point I am seeing our usual links for the search term "stackoverflow"

Comment: Googlebot should take the URL it's being redirect **to** as the canonical one (here doioig.gov says I'm at stackoverflow.com now) But it's the other way around. Kind of strange.

Comment: You got [someone at Google's](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169405/google-indexing-issue-for-keyword-stackoverflow#comment499971_169405) attention: "*I've reproduced it here. I'll report it internally tomorrow - thanks for bringing it up. – Jon Skeet Feb 27 at 21:53*" =)

Comment: interesting.  arguably the SO redirect is the correct one, but the practical experience for most users will be the DOI redirect.  google's right to be confused.  (also i'm not sure what to make of SO being ousted from google by a government programmer blindly copying code from SO.  the mind boggles.)